# VBA Solver Loop: 'SetCell' and 'ByChange' cells changing with each loop (Excel KMV for entire row)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-solver

I am having trouble to handle a VBA loop.

The `Solver` function on Excel allows nonlinear equation solving. I want to use `Solver` to an entire row on Excel `(maxMinVal=2, or Minimize)`.
After a dire search on the internet, yet no hint for my specific problem.

I present the piece of data I am trying to work on [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15zVD6odBi50zZkjCG4Q5BdbaAtF1SQvR/view)  (No download: Google Drive data view).

As (I hope) can be seen, the last column contains the `Squared errors`. I want to minimize this column `(column Q)` through `Nonlinear GRG` (errors are my objective), having as variable cells `"A" (column H)` and `"sigmaA" (column I)` of the same line. It was done already for `Q3 to Q7 (Q12 and Q18 also)`.

**Example:**

> Minimize $Q$8 (0.00021) changing the variable cells $H$8:$I$8 ("A" and
> "sigmaA" of line 8).

I desire a loop to do that same procedure to the entire column of squared residuals (2598 cells).

Until now, I have the VBA script as follows. The `For i=0 to 10` is just to test if the code works for a sample (speeding up calculation):

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 10

' Macro1 Macro
' Solver (Solve nonlinear problems in a row - column format)
    SolverReset

    SolverOk SetCell:="$Q$i", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$H$i:$I$i", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
        
    'Approve the solutions and avoid the popups
    
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    
Next i
    
End Sub
```

When I run the script, either the VBA panel crashes, or it keeps loading a bit long and… nothing happens (the errors do not near 0,000).

This question is **DIFFERENT** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32499197/15250254) since I tried it with `MaxMinVal:=2` and didn’t work (also, in my Solver VBA script `Valueof:=0`). Besides, it did not work for `Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"`

Comment: Anyone out there?